# Parsing StdClass Object from file

Tags: php

I'm using the Superfeedr php client, and when it gets a ping, it json_encodes and then writes the ping to a file. The result is saved as a StdClass Object. I then tried to load the result via file_get_content but I can not access any of the data.

```
$obj = file_get_contents('result.txt');
echo $obj->title;
```

the object is long but looks like:

> stdClass Object (  [status] =>
>   stdClass Object   (    [title] => Blah
>   )  [title] => Blah )

I haven't used PHP in a long time so I'm rusty... but it seems like i'm loading the object as a string thus I can't treat it as a object. Am I right? If so, how do I approach this?

Comment: The content of the file `result.txt` is literally `"stdClass Object ..."`?

Answer (score 1):

This does not appear the "save" an object to a file (which is not really possible anyway), it just dumps the results of `print_r($obj)` into a file. This is only useful for debugging purposes, it's not possible to reconstruct an actual object from this.

You could save the result of `json_encode` to the file, which is something along the lines of this:

```
{"status":{"title":"blah"},"title":"blah",...}
```

This can be `json_decode`'d into an object or array.